# Ubuntu docker image /bin/sh: 1: ufw: not found

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-18.04, ufw

Trying to open a port on an ubuntu 18.04 image and no luck
Running `RUN ufw allow 8080` returns

> /bin/sh: 1: ufw: not found

Any ideas as to how I can open this port or run ufw commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of a container, all ports are open by default to other containers on the same docker network. There is no need to run the `ufw` command, and it is not shipped in images since permissions to change the network are not granted by default (capability NET_ADMIN is not granted).

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [/bin/sh: 1: gvm: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41448227/11154841), which would say more or less:

> Your shell is /bin/sh, but ufw expects /bin/bash, perhaps because it
> puts its initialization in `~/.bashrc`.

Now the accepted answer says that it is not needed. If you still insist on running `ufw`, use

```
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "ufw allow 8080"]
```

Or even better might be to put the commands you want to execute in a single bash script and add that to the image.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

ufw allow 8080
```